# RREF matrix - general solution?

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

1 -1 0 0 | 0

0 0 1 0 | 0

0 0 0 1 | 0

0 0 0 0 | 0

How do I find the general solution with parameters from this RREF matrix? (it's a Homogeneous system, the right-hand side is zero!)

Comment: If your matrix is meant to be augmented there's no solution.

Comment: The general solution to what problem?  Do you have the full augmented matrix?  Was the original problem $A\vec x = \vec 0$, or $A \vec x = \vec b$ for some vector $\vec b$?

Comment: It's a homogeneous system, the right-hand side are all zeros!

Comment: The OP edited his question, so my former comment is no longer valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't calculate, just paint the solution. Expand the matrix
$$\begin{pmatrix}1&-1&0&0\\
0&0&1&0\\
0&0&0&1
\end{pmatrix}$$
to
$$\begin{pmatrix}1&-1&0&0\\
0&-1&0&0&\\
0&0&1&0\\
0&0&0&1
\end{pmatrix}$$
hence the kernel is the span of $\begin{pmatrix}-1\\ -1\\ 0\\ 0\end{pmatrix}$.